# How do you combine and transform multiple arrays/lists of items and avoid duplication via id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

My have a list arrays/items like the ones below. My goal here is to transform these three lists, to ultimately create one list with all the items and all comments, but without duplicating them. Please see below for details:

```
 OldList = [
      {
      personId: 1,
      places:
      [
           {
                id: 1,
                name: 'A',
                comment: 'Yes'
           },
           {
                id: 2,
                name: 'B',
                comment: 'No'
           },
           {
                id: 3,
                name: 'C',
                comment: 'Maybe'
           }
      ]
      },
      {
      personId: 2,
      places:
      [
           {
                id: 2,
                name: 'B',
                comment: 'Yes'
           },
           {
                id: 3,
                name: 'C',
                comment: 'No'
           },
           {
                id: 4,
                name: 'D',
                comment: 'Maybe'
           }
      ]
      },
      {
      personId: 3,
      places:
      [
           {
                id: 3,
                name: 'C',
                comment: 'Yes'
           },
           {
                id: 4,
                name: 'D',
                comment: 'No'
           },
           {
                id: 5,
                name: 'E',
                comment: 'Maybe'
           }
      ]
      }
 ]
```

After combining and transforming these 3 lists, I would like the list to look like this:

```
 NewList:
 [
      {
           id: 1,
           name: 'A',
           comments:
           [
                {
                personId: 1,
                comment: Yes,
                }
           ]
      },
      {
           id: 2,
           name: 'B',
           comments:
           [
                {
                personId: 1,
                comment: 'No',
                },
                {
                personId: 2,
                comment: 'Yes',
                }
           ]
      },
      {
           id: 3,
           name: 'C',
           comments:
           [
                {
                personId: 1,
                comment: 'Maybe',
                },
                {
                personId: 2,
                comment: 'No',
                },
                {
                personId: 3,
                comment: 'Yes',
                }
           ]
      },
      {
           id: 4,
           name: 'D',
           comments:
           [
                {
                personId: 2,
                comment: 'Maybe',
                },
                {
                personId: 3,
                comment: 'No',
                }
           ]
      }, 
      {
           id: 5,
           name: 'E',
           comments:
           [
                {
                personId: 3,
                comment: 'Maybe',
                }
           ]
      }
 ]
```

I have done the following which gives me all the places in one array:

```
 const newList = [].concat(
 ...Object.values(oldList).map(item => item.places)
 );

 console.log(newList)

 [
 {
  id: 1,
   name: 'A',
  comment: 'Yes'
 },
 ....
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = {id1: [{id: 1, name: 'A', comment: 'Yes'}, {id: 2, name: 'B', comment: 'No'}, {id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'Maybe'}], id2:[{id: 2, name: 'B', comment: 'Yes'}, {id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'No'}, {id: 4, name: 'D', comment: 'Maybe'}], id3:[{id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'Yes'}, {id: 4, name: 'D', comment: 'No'}, {id: 5, name: 'E', comment: 'Maybe'}]};
const result = Object.keys(input)
  .reduce((flat, key) => [
    ...flat,
    ...input[key].map(({id, name, comment}) => ({
      id, 
      name, 
      comments: [{
        id: key.slice(-1),
        comment
      }]
    }))
  ], [])
  .reduce((acc, item) => {
    const idx = acc.map(({id}) => id).indexOf(item.id);
    return (idx === -1) ? [...acc, item] : [
      ...acc.slice(0, idx),
      { 
        ...acc[idx],
        comments: [
          ...acc[idx].comments,
          ...item.comments
        ],
      },
      ...acc.slice(idx+1, acc.length)
    ];
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

**EDIT**

> how would you do it if const input = [...]

Basically the same way. Just the first step, to bring the array into a flat format needs to be adjusted:

```js
const input = [{"humanId":1,"comments":[{"id":1,"name":"A","comment":"Yes"},{"id":2,"name":"B","comment":"No"},{"id":3,"name":"C","comment":"Maybe"}]},{"humanId":2,"comments":[{"id":2,"name":"B","comment":"Yes"},{"id":3,"name":"C","comment":"No"},{"id":4,"name":"D","comment":"Maybe"}]},{"humanId":3,"comments":[{"id":3,"name":"C","comment":"Yes"},{"id":4,"name":"D","comment":"No"},{"id":5,"name":"E","comment":"Maybe"}]}];

const result = input.reduce((flat, {humanId, comments}) => [
        ...flat,
        ...comments.map(({id, name, comment}) => ({
            id,
            name,
            comments: [{humanId, comment}],
        }))
    ], [])
    .reduce((acc, item) => {
        const idx = acc.map(({id}) => id).indexOf(item.id);
        return (idx === -1) ? [...acc, item] : [
        ...acc.slice(0, idx),
        { 
            ...acc[idx],
            comments: [
            ...acc[idx].comments,
            ...item.comments
            ],
        },
        ...acc.slice(idx+1, acc.length)
        ];
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works - how would you do it if 
const input = [{humanId: 1, comments: [{ id: 1, name: 'A', comment: 'Yes'}, {id: 2, name: 'B', comment: 'No'}, {id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'Maybe'}]}, {humanId: 2, comments: [{name: 'B', comment: 'Yes'}, {id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'No'}, {id: 4, name: 'D', comment: 'Maybe'}]}, {humanId: 3, comments: [{name: 'C', comment: 'Yes'}, {id: 4, name: 'D', comment: 'No'}, {id: 5, name: 'E', comment: 'Maybe'}]};

Comment: amazing, it works - does this take a lot of power? Say instead of these 9 items, there were thousands?

Comment: That remains to be tested... its not optimised for performance ... let me know if you run into issues on larger datasets

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table and assign the comment to the same group.

Ath the end take the values from the hash table.

```js
var data = { id1: [{ id: 1, name: 'A', comment: 'Yes' }, { id: 2, name: 'B', comment: 'No' }, { id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'Maybe' }], id2: [{ id: 2, name: 'B', comment: 'Yes' }, { id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'No' }, { id: 4, name: 'D', comment: 'Maybe' }], id3: [{ id: 3, name: 'C', comment: 'Yes' }, { id: 4, name: 'D', comment: 'No' }, { id: 5, name: 'E', comment: 'Maybe' }] },
    result = Object.values(Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, array]) => {
        var [key, value] = k.match(/^(.+?)(\d+)$/).slice(1);
        array.forEach(({ id, name, comment }) => {
            var hash = `id${id}`;
            r[hash] = r[hash] || { id, name, comments: [] };
            r[hash].comments.push({ [key]: +value, comment });
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list1 = 
 [
      {
           id: 1,
           name: 'A',
           comment: 'Yes'
      },
      {
           id: 2,
           name: 'B',
           comment: 'No'
      },
      {
           id: 3,
           name: 'C',
           comment: 'Maybe'
      }
];
var list2 =
[
      {
           id: 2,
           name: 'B',
           comment: 'Yes'
      },
      {
           id: 3,
           name: 'C',
           comment: 'No'
      },
      {
           id: 4,
           name: 'D',
           comment: 'Maybe'
      }
 ];

 var list3 = [  
      {
           id: 3,
           name: 'C',
           comment: 'Yes'
      },
      {
           id: 4,
           name: 'D',
           comment: 'No'
      },
      {
           id: 5,
           name: 'E',
           comment: 'Maybe'
      }
];
var mergeDLists = (list1.concat(list2)).concat(list3);
var distinctKeys = Array.from(new Set(mergeDLists.map(t=> t.id))).map(idd=>{
return {
  id :idd,
  name : mergeDLists.find(s => s.id === idd).name,
  comment : mergeDLists.find(s => s.id === idd).comment
  }
});

console.log(distinctKeys);
```

Comment: This does not do what I want it to:
0: {id: 1, name: "A", comment: "Yes"}
1: {id: 2, name: "B", comment: "No"}
2: {id: 3, name: "C", comment: "Maybe"}
3: {id: 4, name: "D", comment: "Maybe"}
4: {id: 5, name: "E", comment: "Maybe"}

Comment: Sorry but your question now is little bit different to what you've requested in the first time , but let me see what's the best solution for it

Answer (score 0):

A more primitive solution but slightly reuseable:

```
let newArray = [];

//create a function that goes through the reference array (the array you want to create) 
//and let's you know if id doesn't already exist, or the index of the object in the 
//reference array if the id exists

function checkIfidExists(id,refArr){ 
  let found = false;
  for(let i=0; i<refArr.length; i++){
    if (refArr[i].id == id){
      found = i; 
      break;
    }
  }
  return found;
}

//create a function that receives the array you want to add as a new object
function newArrayAddition(array, refArray){
  array.map(obj =>{
  //store the index of the object with the id or store falsy value if none is found
  let index = checkIfidExists(obj.id, refArray)
  if(!index){
    refArray.push({
      id: obj.id,
      name: obj.name,
      comments: [
        {
          id : 1,
          comment: obj.comment
        }
      ]
    })
  }else{
    refArray[index].comments.push({
      id: refArray[index].comments.length + 1,
      comment: obj.comment
    })
  }
})
}


newArrayAddition(id1, newArray);
newArrayAddition(id2, newArray);
newArrayAddition(id3, newArray);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks as if you are trying to reindex from an array of Persons to an array of Places. The following function would do that for any given array shaped like your example:

```
const reindexArray = (inputArray) => {
  const outputArray = [];

  inputArray.forEach(currentPerson => {
    currentPerson.forEach(currentPlace => {

      const indexInOutput = outputArray
        .map(outputItem => outputItem.id)
        .indexOf(currentPlace.id);

      if (indexInOutput === -1) {
        outputArray.push({
          id: currentPlace.id,
          name: currentPlace.name,
          comments: [{
            personId: currentPerson.personId,
            comment: currentPlace.comment,
          }],
        })
      } else {
        outputArray[indexInOutput]
          .comments
          .push({
            personId: currentPerson.personId,
            comment: currentPlace.comment,
          });
      }
    });
  });

  return outputArray;

};
```

Comment: Thanks - what would the changes look like?

Comment: Hey, can you look at my updated question? I used your second method, but I'm getting a list of objects like this { id: 1, name: 'A', comment: 'Yes'} but I'd like this: { id: 1, name: 'A', comment: 'Yes', friendId: 1}

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the edit on your question